# netsuite saved search criteria issue need to block items based on sku

Tags: netsuite, saved-searches

I am creating a saved search however some of my itemtypes contain a -BT in the SKU and i want to make it so those items do not show up in the saved search

this is where i was heading however it seems netsuite doesn't like this

CASE WHEN CONTAINS({SKU (Custom)}, '-BT') THEN '0' ELSE '1' END
and then set is to 1

Answer (score 0):

A formula numeric field will do the trick. Set your criteria to == 0 and use this formula where `custitem...` should be the scripting id of your custom sku field

`instr({custitem...}, '-BT')`